# SQL Lite is giving an "index out of range" error

Tags: sqlite

When I run this code in Rust

```
statement.read::<i64, _>("creation_utc").unwrap(),
```

I get,

> Error { code: None, message: Some("the index is out of range (`creation_utc`)") }

But I've verified the column is in the table multiple times. What problem causes this and how can I resolve this error?

Comment: What do you mean by, *But I've verified the column is in the table multiple times* ? SQLite is tagged , but no sql code is used in the question. It seems to me that there are a lot of missing information in the question

Comment: @ErgestBasha it's self answered.

Comment: *it's self answered* yeah I saw . The point of my comment was to help others viewers who might have the same issue.  As it is question-answer it seems like a documentation thing to me (maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a mismatch between the table and the result set returned by the query. You need only add that missing column to your select list,

```sql
SELECT foo, bar, creation_utc
FROM table
```